# How to call data from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html

I have to call data from an HTML page for my PHP page. Here is the code:

```
> <div id="wrapper">

<h3>Bill Calculator</h3>

<form action="bill.php" method="get">

<p>Number of people eating:
<select name="num_people">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Amount of meal bill: <input type="text" name="bill" size="8" maxlength="8"></p>

<p>Tip percentage:   
<select name="tip">
        <option value=".15">15%</option>
        <option value=".18">18%</option>
        <option value=".20">20%</option>
</select>
</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></p>

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
> <html>
<head>
    <title>Bill</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <?
    $tip=$_POST['tip'];
    $bill=$_POST['bill'];
    $num_people=$_POST['num_people'];
        $total = ($bill * $tip) * num_people;
        echo "Each person owes $total";

 ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

I need to call the bill, tip and amount of people then multiply bill and tip then divide by the amount of people to know how much one person owes.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using $_POST in your PHP, your html form should use POST

Answer (score 1):

your form method is get

```
<form action="bill.php" method="get">
```

so either you use the $_GET[''] method in your php code

or you change your form method to post

```
<form action="bill.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Hi,I am getting this "Undefined index: tip "

Comment: that is because you dont check if $_POST['tip'] exists before you try to use it's value.   you need to do   if(isset($_POST['tip'])){ $tip=$_POST['tip'];}  same goes for all $_POST variables

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. My code is like this now:<html>
<head>
 <title>Bill</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <?
 if(isset($_POST['tip'])){ $tip=$_POST['tip'];}
 if(isset($_POST['bill'])){ $tip=$_POST['bill'];}
if(isset($_POST['num_people'])){ $tip=$_POST['num_people'];}  
 $total = ($bill * $tip) / $num_people;
  echo "Each person owes $total";
 
 ?>    
</body>
</html>

Comment: `$bill = 0;
$tip = 0;
$num_people = 1;
if(isset($_POST['tip']))
{ $tip=$_POST['tip'];}
if(isset($_POST['bill'])){ $tip=$_POST['bill'];}
if(isset($_POST['num_people'])){ $tip=$_POST['num_people'];}
$total = ($bill * $tip) / $num_people;
echo "Each person owes $total";`

Comment: Now it says "Each person owes 0"

Comment: Now im getting. bill: 0
tip: 0
numpeople: 1
Each person owes 0

Comment: the code works ^^ let's try it another way  copy the entire code from http://pastebin.com/SW61XBuk and paste it into your bill.php file then run the file on your webserver

Answer (score -1):

In its form, the method is `GET`. In the PHP page you try to get them to `POST`.

```
<form action="bill.php" method="get">
```

Change to:

```
<form action="bill.php" method="POST">
```

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

> **GET** requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as
>   using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this
>   is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which
>   should not need to consider the side effects that a request should
>   cause.

and

> **POST** submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request.
>   This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of
>   existing resources or both.

So essentially `GET` is used to retrieve remote data, and `POST` is used to insert/update remote data.

Comment: While this does answer the question, it would probably help a new user if you explain what the difference is between these two lines and why the change is necessary.